# detect alphabetical and numerical order in R

Tags: r, alphabetical, numerical

I would need a R code that tells me whether the values in each row have been placed in alphabetical and numerical order, for each row. By alphabetical order I mean comparing the cells in each column of a row, starting from the first cell to the last one.  An example of alphabetical_row = c(A61B, H01J, H03B, G01Q).

```
row1 <- c("G01N 23/20", "G01N 23/203", "G01Q 30/00", "G01Q 30/04", "G01Q 30/18", "H01J 37/252", "H01J 37/252")
row2 <- c("G01S 7/38", "G01S 7/38", "H03B 21/00", "H03B 21/02", NA, NA, NA)
row3 <- c("A61B 8/00", "A61B 8/00", "G01S 7/52", "G01S 7/52", NA, NA, NA)

 df <-      data.frame(rbind(row1, row2, row3))
```

The output I am looking for is a new column with TRUE, in case the values in the row are in order, or FALSE, in case the values are not in order, for each row.

However, lets start with the first 4 digits:

```
row1 <- c("G01N", "G01N", "G01Q", "G01Q", "G01Q", "H01J", "H01J")
row2 <- c("G01S", "G01S", "H03B", "H03B", NA, NA, NA)
row3 <- c("A61B", "A61B", "G01S", "G01S", NA, NA, NA)

 df <-      data.frame(rbind(row1, row2, row3))
```

Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(df, c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)))
```

in this case the output would be: FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, because only row3 is in alphabetical order, from cell 1 (A61B) to cell 4 (G01S).

Comment: Can you edit your R code syntax so that it doesn't cause errors? (Also, maybe rename `row1` to `col1`...)

Comment: An example of desired output would also be nice. Alphabetical order and numeric order are different, and example output for this input would help clear up any confusion. For example, `G01N 23/20` is before `G01N 23/203` alphabetically, and numerically if the `/` is part of a string, but after it if we treat `/` as division. But division doesn't make sense because you have `30/00` later, and you can't divide by 0.

Comment: can you provide an example of a TRUE and FALSE? is G01N 23/2 FALSE because numerically its not ordered?

Comment: Please explain the logic of the result? Starting with the first 4 digits, it looks to me like every row is in alphabetical order. For example, the first row,  `G01N < G01Q < H01J`. `N` comes before `Q`, and `G` comes before `H`. Why is your result `FALSE`? Row 2 is also in alphabetical order, because `G` is before `H`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will test for alphabetical order, and also require the `NA` values are last. Your sample data uses `factor` columns, but I would strongly recommend converting them to `character` (with `as.character()`) since rows rather than columns are meaningful. If the columns of the data frame are character, then you can leave out the `as.character()` part of the answer. If you want to adjust the `NA` behavior, see `?order` for options.

```
df$ordered = apply(df, 1, function(x) identical(order(as.character(x)), seq_along(x)))

df 
#        X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7 ordered
# row1 G01N G01N G01Q G01Q G01Q H01J H01J    TRUE
# row2 G01S G01S H03B H03B <NA> <NA> <NA>    TRUE
# row3 A61B A61B G01S G01S <NA> <NA> <NA>    TRUE
```